# Agora Video Call[Android] one to one private video call is not establishing group call is establishing

Tags: android, agora.io, videocall

i need to make one to one private video calls with agora video sdk android
The problem is a third person should not be merged in my current running video the person should wait for another 4th person to come online he must not merge into current running video call how should i resolve this? 
what should i do in order to make one to one calls 
thanks in advance

Comment: Your application logic should make the third person wait for the fourth person before joining the channel.

Answer (score 0):

for this, instead of rendering the third people’s remote video, you should save the third people’s UID. when receiving the fourth people’s UID, you can render the thrid and fourth people’s videos at the same time. The method you can receive remote user’s UID is onRemoteVideoStateChanged callback.